# prevent xbindkeys from overriding mouse click when used for mouse button chording

Tags: x11, mouse, xbindkeys

I am trying to set up some mouse button chording, inspired by the Acme text editor: http://acme.cat-v.org/mouse

On Windows and Mac, I was able to set up the following using AutoHotKey and Hammerspoon respectively:

```
Left+Middle   = Cut   (Ctrl+x)
Left+Right    = Paste (Ctrl+v)
Middle+Left   = Return
Middle+Right  = Space
Right+Left    = Undo  (Ctrl+z)
Right+Middle  = Redo  (Ctrl+Y / Ctrl+Shift+z)

Middle+Scroll = Switch window
```

Having moved from Windows to Linux for my main computer, I'm trying to set up the same on Linux. I am running OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with X11 and XFCE.

For simplicity, I'll focus only on cut (`Left+Middle = Ctrl+x`) for the following code examples.

---

Using `xev` I've found that while the left mouse button is down, the `state` variable is set to `0x100`.

So a simple configuration for cut would be:

```
"xdotool key ctrl+x"
    m:0x100 + b:2
```

This does not work, and I get the infamous warning of conflicting program:

```
*** Warning ***
Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
grab all the keys defined in its configuration file.
```

`m:0x4 + b:2` does work (0x4 being Ctrl), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Is there a way to get this to work?**

---

Searching around I've found some setups for mouse chording, which I was able to adapt to my needs. These requires guile-support in xbindkeys though.

`.xbindkeysrc.scm`

```
(define actionperformed 0)

(define (first-binding)
"First binding"
  (xbindkey-function '("b:1") b1-second-binding) ;; Left Mouse Button
)

(define (reset-first-binding)
"Reset first binding"
  (ungrab-all-keys)
  (remove-all-keys)
  (set! actionperformed 0)
  (first-binding)
  (grab-all-keys)
)


(define (b1-second-binding)
"Left Mouse Button"
  (remove-all-keys)
  (ungrab-all-keys)

  (run-command "xdotool mousedown 1 &") ;; <--- THIS DOES NOT WORK! 

  ;; Left+Middle
  (xbindkey-function '("b:2")
    (lambda ()
      ;; Copy
      (run-command "xdotool key ctrl+x&")
      (run-command "xdotool mouseup 1&")
      (set! actionperformed 1)
    )
  )

  ;; Release left
  (xbindkey-function '(release "b:1") 
    (lambda ()
      (unless actionperformed (begin
        (run-command "xdotool mouseup 1&"))) 
      (reset-first-binding)
    )
  )
  (grab-all-keys)
)

(first-binding)
```

This does make Left+Middle perform a cut operation.

The problem is that the Left click is overridden, and I can therefore not make a simple left click or a text selection.

I added `xdotool mousedown 1` to fix this, but it doesn't work.

`xdotool` seems to not be able to trigger a mouse-event while the same mouse event is active.

**Is there any way to prevent xbindkeys from overriding the normal action of buttons?**

---

I have another mouse with a button 9, using this I can at least set up something.

Since all the button chords must start with the same button I can only really get 3 chords (+ scrolling), which is half of what I want.

Pressing the buttons is also very awkward, and I can't consider this a permanent solution:

```
(define (first-binding)
  (xbindkey-function '("b:9") second-binding)
)

(define (second-binding)
  (remove-all-keys)
  (ungrab-all-keys)

  (xbindkey-function '("b:2") (lambda () (run-command "xdotool key ctrl+x")))

  (xbindkey-function '(Release "b:9") reset-first-binding)
)

(define (reset-first-binding)
  (ungrab-all-keys)
  (remove-all-keys)
  (first-binding)
  (grab-all-keys)
)

(first-binding)
```

**Any ideas on ways to solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, but the workaround is a bit complicated (compared to the windows and mac versions anyway).

The idea is to use `xinput` to remap the mouse buttons for the usb mouse, causing the buttons to not function, but retaining the mouse movements.

Then listen to the mouse button events with `evtest` and trigger the mouse chording commands for detected button combos, or trigger normal button events when no combo is detected.

1. install `xinput` and `evtest`
2. run `evtest` and make note of your usb mouse (something like `/dev/input/event3`)
3. run `xinput -list` and make note of the device id
4. run `xinput set-button-map {id} 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` (10 zeroes)
5. run `evtest /dev/input/event3 | ./mouse-chording.pl`

content of `mouse-chording.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -wlnF/\s|,/

BEGIN
{
    our %btns         = (272 => 0, 273 => 0, 274 => 0);
    our $active_chord = 0;

    # mouse button codes
    our $left_code   = 272;
    our $right_code  = 273;
    our $middle_code = 274;
    our $scroll_code = 8;
}

# only handle events
next unless  0 == index $_, 'Event';
next unless -1 == index $_, 'SYN';

# extract event values
my ($time, $type, $code, $value) = @F[2, 5, 9, 13];

# skip mouse movements and hi-res scroll
next if $code == 11;
next if $type == 2 && $code != 8;

# keep track of pressed buttons
$btns{$code} = $value;

# emulate button presses
if ( ($code == $left_code   && !($btns{$right_code} || $btns{$middle_code}))
  || ($code == $right_code  && !($btns{$left_code}  || $btns{$middle_code}))
  || ($code == $middle_code && !($btns{$left_code}  || $btns{$right_code})) )
{
    if ($code == $left_code)
    {
        # left button can be held for selecting text
        system $value ? "xdotool mousedown 1&" : "xdotool mouseup 1&";
    }
    elsif($value == 0 && not $active_chord)
    {
        # middle and right will only trigger click - cannot be held
        system "xdotool click " . ($code == $middle_code ? 2 : 3) . "&";
    }

    $active_chord = 0;
    next;
}
# emulate scroll wheel
elsif ($code == 8)
{
    system( sprintf("xdotool click %d&", $value > 0 ? 4 : 5) );
}

# only do chords when button is pressed (not released)
next unless $value;

# Left + Middle = Cut
if ($btns{$left_code} && $code == $middle_code)
{
    system "xdotool mouseup 1&"; # prevent accidental selection after snarf
    system "xdotool key ctrl+c key ctrl+x&";
    $active_chord = 1;
    next;
}

# Left + Right = Paste
if ($btns{$left_code} && $code == $right_code)
{
    system "xdotool key ctrl+v&";
    $active_chord = 1;
    next;
}

END
{
    # release buttons to prevent getting stuck when closing
    system "xdotool mouseup $_&" for (1..3);
}
```

This solution is maintained along side the windows and mac versions on github: https://github.com/levigutt/mouse-chording/

PRs are welcome! :)